# Getting error with npx react-native start command

Tags: react-native, terminal

As when I run `sudo npx react-native start` cmd on VSCode terminal for react-native development I have encountered with following error.

```
watchmanResponse: {
    error: 'resolve_projpath: path `/Users/esoft/Documents/Rutuja/Myapp1/myApp1`: open: /Users/esoft/Documents/Rutuja/Myapp1/myApp1: Operation not permitted',
    version: '4.9.0'
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is your OS? Is it the path to your own user directory? /Users/esoft/Documents/Rutuja
Are you working on your personal computer or is it your company computer, which might have specific security rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are in **Linux** based OS, try running this command to give permissions to the dir

```sh
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

### I think You Follow from this two at beginning level:

To change the permissions for Watchman regarding the Documents folder, it's under Security & Privacy -> files & folders in the system preferences

### OR

Try to change the directory of your project. I had mine on desktop and was getting that error, moved to the home folder and the error is gone